# Вывод текста из textArea в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Пытаюсь написать метод вывода текста из одной textArea в другую (окно чата) по нажатию на кнопку Enter.

```
    public void textAction(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {    
              if (!textField.getText().equals("")) {
                    textArea.appendText(textField.getText() + "\n");
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                    textField.clear();
                    textField.requestFocus();
                }
            }
   }
```

Проблема в том, что после такого ввода происходит переброс коретки в поле ввода на новую строку, не понимаю, как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное что подошло под ваше описание, это использование в роли поля с именем `textField` поля типа `TextArea` (если это так и есть, обращайте на это больше внимания в дальнейшем). Используйте [event.consume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume()):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        //final TextField textField = new TextField();
        final TextArea textField = new TextArea();
        textField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                String text = textField.getText().trim();
                if ( !text.isEmpty() ) {
                    textArea.appendText(text);
                    textArea.appendText(System.lineSeparator());
                    //mediaPlayer.play();
                    textField.clear();
                    //textField.requestFocus();
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(textArea, textField), 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```